# Repeating Bow for Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm looking for a way to have a standard Bow and Arrow fire rapidly so that it has an effect like a gun. I saw something similar to it on a Private Server but I forgot what it's called.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, we don't really support questions asking for recommendations of games, mods, or other content like this.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Let me rephrase the question

Comment: It's still asking for a recommendation.  Rather than ask for something that does X, tell us what problem it is you're trying to solve.  Something like, "Can I make a repeating bow?  If so, how?".  That way, any answers provided can tell you how to do so, and it doesn't require a mod or other recommendation.

Comment: No such enchantment exists. The server was likely using a plugin or mod.

Comment: This was possible until `MC Beta 1.7` I think. In that release (and before) you did not need to stretch the bow, so you were able to use it as you describe.

Answer (score -2):

You have to have a mod called Rapid Arrows Mod. It is for PC only.

Comment: Could you improve your answer by adding a link to this mod?

Comment: And how to use this mod to achieve what the asker wants?